# PHP: How to display several, random images with array_rand?

Tags: php

I'm using this script to display one random image from a folder with subfolders:

```
<?php
$imagesDir = glob('folders/pics/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$randomfolder = $imagesDir[array_rand($imagesDir)];
$images = glob($randomfolder . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
echo '<img src="'.$randomImage.'" class="image">'; 
?>
```

Everything works fine! But for now I want to show 5 images at the same time (for a caroussel-slider). I used the following code

```
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images, 5)];
```

but it shows me this warning:

> Warning: Illegal offset type […]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `array_rand()` function wrong. It will return an `array` of keys, not a single number. What you could do is:

```
$randomImageKeys = array_rand($images, 5);
for ($randomImageKeys as $key) {
   echo '<img src="'.$images[$key].' class="image">';
}
```

> But like this you risk an **E_WARNING** if your `$images` array contains less
>   than 5 images - to avoid this, you could use the following:

```
$max = (count($images) < 5) ? count($images) : 5;
$randomImageKeys = array_rand($images, $max);
for ($randomImageKeys as $key) {
   echo '<img src="'.$images[$key].' class="image">';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works fine! And to all the other helping hands: Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$randomImageIndexes = array_rand($images, 5);

foreach ($randomImageIndexes as $imageIndex){

   echo $images[$imageIndex];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `array_rand($array, $n)` returns an array if `$n > 1` (c.f. [php.net documentation : array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)), you have to iterate through the result to make your script work.

It should works fine this way :

```
<?php
$imagesDir = glob('folders/pics/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$randomfolder = $imagesDir[array_rand($imagesDir)];
$images = glob($randomfolder . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach(array_rand($images) as $imageIndex)
    echo '<img src="'.$images[$imageIndex].'" class="image">';
```